# Not able to use a Model Property in html template

Tags: python, html, django, view, model

I am making a E-commerce app for electronics and I Have made separate models for each category.
So at the cart page I am not able to sum the total value of the items.

I got this error

AttributeError at /cart/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'
Exception Location: D:\WebDev\my_projects\techcastle\store\models.py in get_laptop_total, line 123
Python Executable:  D:\WebDev\my_projects\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0

My Model : -

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url                

class Laptop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url      

class Accessories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url      

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems  = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_laptop_total for item in orderitems] + sum([item.get_mobile_total for item in orderitems]) 
        + sum([item.get_acc_total for item in orderitems] ))
        return total      
    
    @property
    def get_cart_item(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total 
    
    

     


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product_m = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    product_l = models.ForeignKey(Laptop,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    product_a = models.ForeignKey(Accessories,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if (self.product_l is not None):
            return (self.product_l.name)
        elif (self.product_a is not None):
            return (self.product_a.name)
        elif (self.product_m is not None):
            return (self.product_m.name)    

    @property
    def get_mobile_total(self):
        total_m =  self.product_m.price * self.quantity
        return total_m    

    @property
    def get_acc_total(self):
        total_a =  self.product_a.price * self.quantity
        return total_a   
    
    @property
    def get_laptop_total(self):
        total_l =  self.product_l.price * self.quantity
        return total_l
```

My view

```
def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,completed=False)
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
     

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order }
    return render(request,'store/cart.html',context)
```

template

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'store' %}">&#x2190; Continue Shopping</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">

                    <tr>
                        <th><h5>Items : <strong> {{order.get_cart_item}}</strong></h5></th>
                        **<th><h5>Total : <strong> {{order.get_cart_total}}  </strong></h5></th>
                        <th>**
                            <a  style="float:right; margin:5px;" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My theory: in your Order.get_cart_total() you call the sum function for laptops on every item in your cart without checking wheter or not it is assigned to a laptop with a foreign key. Same for mobile and acc. So in your OrderItem methods you need to first check wheter or not it is a laptop. Try:

```
def get_laptop_total(self):  
   if self.product_l:  
       total_l =  self.product_l.price * self.quantity  
       return total_l
   else:
       return 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can sleep peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

django is a case-sensitive language. you should check the spelling of the class name you've mentioned in the `def get_cart_item(self)` and `def get_cart_total(self)`.
it should be:-

```
@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    orderitems  = self.Orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_laptop_total for item in orderitems] + sum([item.get_mobile_total for item in orderitems]) 
    + sum([item.get_acc_total for item in orderitems] ))
    return total      

@property
def get_cart_item(self):
    orderitems = self.Orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
    return total
```

Comment: Actually only the def get_cart_total(self): is causing the error and def get_cart_item(self): works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.product_l.price * self.quantity` in `get_laptop_total`, try `self.product_l__price * self.quantity`. i hope this works.